# Adding auto-complete to custom gravity field not working

Tags: custom-field, jquery, plugin-gravity-forms, autocomplete

I am trying to add auto-complete to my custom fields on gravity forms.But its not working.Data returns but not showing on field.I am doing like this:

```
(function( jQuery ) {
    jQuery(function() {
        var url = ajaxurl + "?action=my_search";
        jQuery( "#input_22_2" ).autocomplete({
            source: url,
            minLength: 2
        }); 
    });

})( jQuery );
```

PHP Code :

```
function my_search() {
   global $wpdb;
        $term = strtolower( $_GET['term'] );



         $query = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_vhh4zdnv0r_disease WHERE scifi_name like '%".$_GET['term']."%' OR hospital_code like '%".$_GET['term']."%' OR layman_language like '%".$_GET['term']."%'");
    if ( $query )
    {
        foreach ( $query as  $valuek) {

           if(strpos($valuek->scifi_name,$_GET['term']) !== false){
            $row[] = $valuek->scifi_name;
           }


        }
    }

        $response = json_encode( $row );
        echo $response;
        exit();

}

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_search', 'my_search' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem using below code.So may be helpful for someone.I have tried by reference style for autocomplete

```
<script>

    var locations = '<?php echo $json;?>';
var locations_array = JSON.parse(locations);
 locations_array.sort();


    function monkeyPatchAutocomplete2() {
            jQuery("#result").remove();
          // Don't really need to save the old fn, 
          // but I could chain if I wanted to
          var oldFn = jQuery.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem;

          jQuery.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function( ul, item) {
              var re = new RegExp( "\\b" + this.term, "i") ;
              var t = item.label.replace(re,"<span class='highlighted'>" + this.term + "</span>");
              return jQuery( "<li></li>" )
                  .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                  .append( "<a>" + t + "</a>" )
                  .appendTo( ul );

          };
      }


      jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery('.medication input').live('keyup', function (event) {

    if(this.value.length < 2){
        jQuery("#result").remove();
    } 

          monkeyPatchAutocomplete2();
          //jQuery("#result").remove();
           jQuery( ".medication input" ).autocomplete({

            matchContains: true,
            multiselect: true,            
             minLength: 2,
              source: function(req, responseFn) {

                  //addMessage("search on: '" + req.term + "'<br/>");
                  var re = jQuery.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term);
                  var matcher = new RegExp(  "\\b" + re, "i" );
                  var a = jQuery.grep( locations_array, function(item,index){
                      //addMessage("&nbsp;&nbsp;sniffing: '" + item + "'<br/>");
                      return matcher.test(item);
                  }); 


                  responseFn( a );
              },
              focus: function (event, ui) {

                jQuery("#result").remove();
                return false;
            },
          });


});


 </script>
```